# how to keyboard on after clicking in textfield

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

i Have a UITextField and a TableView
When I click on textField then Tableview appear with popover controller and Keyboard is hidden automatically so i dont want to hide Keyboard after cliked on textfield How can i do this , I want to perform Two task when i click on textfield. keyboard should not hidden

Comment: Please elaborate your question...thx

Answer (score 1):

Set UITextField as the `firstresponder` after the touch happen's. It may solve your issue.